# Fetching Twitter Share Count for site url using Spring Java Rest Service

Tags: java, spring, rest, twitter

As part of current caching system, we are trying to fetch twitter share count for our site url using "https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=" . We call this API from Spring Java Rest Controller. This Api works fine for few attempts for the same url. But many time this is throwing timeout exception even after retrial.

We tried to run curl command on above API for same url from APP server and we see the same behavior. Do we know, why it is happening. Does twitter blocks server Ip address if many requests comes from same server. Is it the right API to get count for a url or do we need to use different API.

Any help in this regard will be great.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

I just found one solution to do that.

API URL : `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=www.myABCwebsite.com`

Look for the following field under "statuses" object.

```
"statuses_count": 6400,
```

Comment: Hi Joshi,Thanks a lot for answering this. When I hit this url , I get "Bad Authentication data". I am not sure how to pass authentication values . I have customer access key and Access Token but not sure, how to pass those.  How did you get this output any idea?

Comment: Hi Joshi,I figured out a way to hot this url. I tried this url with my outh1 login from twitter API UI and I get multiple values for a particular url. For example:  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=http://www.foxsports.com/nascar/story/tony-stewart-retire-driver-2016-last-season-behind-wheel-sprint-cup-kevin-ward-092715                                    For Above url "cdn.api.twitter.com" return 186 . But from search url I see many statuses_count and none of these matches count 186. Let me know, if there is any specific way to get the counts using API which you mentioned.

Comment: Look for the mentioned field in the response.